# How to make ajax call through wp-mvc plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am developing plugin with help `wpmvc` plugin.
I am facing problem to Ajax call.

I have added `router.php` file.

```
MvcRouter::admin_ajax_connect(array('controller' => 'tbl_projects', 'action' => 'show'));
```

I have create `show()` action in controller file and `show.php` file in view folder.
I have added js function in js file:

```
        url : ajaxurl,
        data : {
            action : 'tbl_projects_controller_show',
            postData : ''
        },
        dataType : "html",
        type : 'post',
```

I am getting '0' response when the Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Following should help you move on:
http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL so that it may help you:

http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

I too am looking for the same thing as you do... If you arrive at a solution please do share it so that i too can solve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

1. In **your-plugin/app/config/router.php** file add:

   ```
   MvcRouter::admin_ajax_connect(array('controller' => 'adminprojects', 'action' => 'ajaxshow'));
   ```
2. In **your-plugin/controllers/admin/admin_projects_controller.php**
   file add:

   ```
   class AdminProjectsController extends MvcAdminController {
       public function ajaxshow() {
           // also can use $_POST['content']
           echo 'GOT IT:' . $this->params['content'];
           die();
       }
   }
   ```

   **Attention to:** controller class name and controller variable pass in **admin_ajax_connect** function.
3. Now you can use a code like this:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {

       // Data to send to the AJAX call
       var data = {
           action: 'adminprojects_ajaxshow',
           content: 'Run from myplugin ajax'
       };

       // ajaxurl is defined by WordPress
       jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
           // Handle the response
           console.log(response);
       });
   });
   ```